# Prove $5\sin x - 4\cos x < 9$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers

My attempt at proving is as follows:

If

$-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$ and $1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$

then

$5(-1) - 4(-1) = -5 + 4 = -1$

$5(1) - 4(1) = 5 - 4 = 1$

so

$-1 \leq 5 \sin x - 4\cos x \leq 1 < 9$

thus

$5\sin x - 4\cos x < 9$

But I know this is not legitimate as for some values of $x$, $5\sin x-4\cos x$ is not within the domain $[-1,1]$.

Could someone please point me in the right direction towards correcting this?

Many thanks,

Jake

Comment: Is your title really what you wanted to write?

Comment: Ah, sorry! That was a bad start! Thanks

Comment: Ingredients: Factor out $\sqrt{41}$ from left hand side and rewrite $\frac{5}{\sqrt{41}}sinx-\frac{4}{\sqrt{41}}cosx$ in the form $sinAcosB-cosAsinB$ and realize that the pyhtagorean theorem is really what you are looking for.

Comment: Your title has 5 sin(x)- 4 sin(x) which is just sin(x).  Clearly, you mean 5 sin(x) - 4 cos(x).  Your error is assuming that you take sin(x) and cos(x) to be 1 and -1 at the same time.  The largest that sin(x) can be is 1 and the **smallest** cos(x) can be is -1 so 5 sin(x)-  4 cos(x) cannot possibly be larger than 5(1)- 4(-1)= 9.  This does NOT say that 5 sin(x)- 4 cos(x) is ever equal to 9, just that it is never larger than that.

Comment: Say that $5|\sin x|\leq5$ and $4|\cos x|\leq 4$ so $5\sin x-4\cos x\leq 9$ you can see that the inequality doesn't follow since when $\sin x=1$ and $\cos x=-1$ can not hold at the same time.

Comment: Oh that's it! I was assuming that the value for both sin and cos would be the same, duh! Thanks all

Comment: You mean, I think, that the **equality** does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

Express $5\sin x - 4 \cos x $ in the form $R\sin(x-\theta)$ where $R$ is the largest value attainable by the function
$$
R\sin(x-\theta)=R(\sin x \cos \theta -\cos x \sin \theta )
$$
Comparing coefficients of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ in this form with your original yields
$$
R\cos \theta=5, R \sin \theta=-4
$$
Square and add
$$
R^2 = 41
$$
and
$$
R \approx 6.40 \lt 9
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) to
the vectors $u = (5, -4)$ and $v = (\sin x, \cos x)$:
$$
 5 \sin x - 4 \cos x \le \sqrt{5^2 + 4^2} \sqrt {\sin^2x + \cos^2x }
 = \sqrt{41} \approx 6.4 < 9 \, .
$$

The bound $\sqrt{41}$ is sharp, equality holds if $u$ and $v$ are
a non-negative multiples of each other, i.e. if $\tan x = -\frac 54 $.

Answer (score 0):

Since $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$, it is clear that

$$5\sin x - 4\cos x \leq 9$$

So, we only need to show that the expression can never be equal to $9$.

The only way to make it equal to $9$, is to make sure that $\sin(x) = 1$ and $\cos(x) = -1$ for the same $x$.

Now, this sets restrictions upon $x$.

We must both have

$$x = \pi/2 + k2\pi$$ and $$x = k2\pi$$ for a certain integer $k$

It is clear that such an integer does not exist, therefore, the expression is always smaller than $9$.

Answer (score 0):

We know $|5\sin x|\leq5$ and $|4cosx|\leq4$.

Say $5sinx-4cosx \geq 9$.

So $|5sinx-4cosx|\geq 9$.

Hence $9\leq|5sinx-4cosx|\leq |5sinx|+|4cosx|\leq 9$ (By triangle inequality)

Hence $5sinx=5$ and $4cosx=4$, but this cannot happen simultaneously, hence a contradiction.

Comment: You can use `\sinx` instead of `sinx` for better appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = 5\sin x - 4\cos x$ be defined on $[-\pi, \pi]$. Then $f'(x) = 5\cos x+ 4\sin x$. We have that $f'(x) = 0$ when $\tan(x) = -\frac 5 4$. The solutions to this equation are $x_1 = \tan^{-1}\left(-\frac 5 4 \right)$ and $x_2 = \pi+x_1$. Then
$$f(-\pi) = f(\pi) = -5$$
$$f(x_1) = -\sqrt{41}$$
$$f(x_2) = \sqrt{41}$$
And so we can see that $f(x)\leq \sqrt{41}\approx 6.4$.

Answer (score 0):

*A very simple solution* (no computation):

We know that for all $x$, $\sin x\le 1$, $\;-\cos x<1$, hence
$$5\sin x-4\cos x\le 9.$$
Thus all we have to prove is we can't have $5\sin x-4\cos x=9$. TThe equality would imply both $\sin x=1$ *and* $\cos x=-1$. As we all know, this can't happen.